# jasper reports grouping - dont want to reset page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using group by city to calculate the amount from the city and print it on the each line

Its creating new page and resetting the page number on change of City, which is not required.

I have not provided any of these isStartNewPage="true" isResetPageNumber="true"

Can you help me to resolve this, Below is the JRXML I am using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2016-02-28T08:45:17 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Sample" pageWidth="960" pageHeight="894" columnWidth="960" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="c90be235-8362-48ce-8745-330a4fd0ea12">
    <field name="CUSTOMER_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="YTD_SALES" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ADDRESS_1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ADDRESS_2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ZIP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="STATE_YTD" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YTD_SALES}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0.00]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="OH_CITY_YTD" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group2" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{YTD_SALES}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0.00]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group2" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="Group1" isResetPageNumber="true" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATE}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="32">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="94" height="16" uuid="bd6bfb15-00e9-4186-87e3-ead6e6919370">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[.]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="115" y="16" width="94" height="16" uuid="35091209-9f04-4545-9d44-455cd6bb9b63">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[TOT YTD SALES]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField pattern="##,###,###,###.00 ;##,###,###,###.00-" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="216" y="16" width="130" height="16" uuid="fad0c099-068c-458e-b854-9f77fc75148b">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{STATE_YTD}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="64" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="8" height="16" uuid="4ded6cc1-a920-4d21-9d11-b48b4bf165ce">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="8" y="0" width="58" height="16" uuid="35091209-9f04-4545-9d44-455cd6bb9b63">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[RUN DATE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yy  hh:mm:ss">
                <reportElement x="72" y="0" width="130" height="16" uuid="fad0c099-068c-458e-b854-9f77fc75148b">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="785" y="0" width="80" height="16" uuid="f39e4155-d285-43e5-a4d0-687b76a52de7">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[REPORT PAGE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="893" y="0" width="22" height="16" uuid="7220d7e8-8cbf-4814-9dac-7f1595f337a3">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="634" height="16" uuid="ae9f123c-c840-42cb-b7d3-a5a4e82e7790"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="0.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ PRG. NO. 123                            CUSTOMERS SHIP TO ADDRESSES AND YTD SALES]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="634" height="16" uuid="ae9f123c-c840-42cb-b7d3-a5a4e82e7790"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="0.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[                                                                                               ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="476" y="32" width="29" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf("(").concat($F{STATE}).concat(")")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="48" width="634" height="16" uuid="ae9f123c-c840-42cb-b7d3-a5a4e82e7790"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="0.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[   .                                                                                            ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="792" height="16" uuid="0c8cb5ef-8a0f-49eb-8f4a-e4ef3d5b8101">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[     CUST NUM        SHIP TO NAME                   ADDRESS 1                   ADDRESS 2                 CITY]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="792" height="16" uuid="0c8cb5ef-8a0f-49eb-8f4a-e4ef3d5b8101">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[     --------        ------------                   ---------                   ---------                 ----]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="792" height="16" uuid="0c8cb5ef-8a0f-49eb-8f4a-e4ef3d5b8101">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ .                                                                                              ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="36" y="0" width="58" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CUSTOMER_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="36" y="16" width="101" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[String.valueOf("ZIP ").concat($F{ZIP})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="144" y="0" width="180" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="144" y="16" width="65" height="16" uuid="0c8cb5ef-8a0f-49eb-8f4a-e4ef3d5b8101">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[YTD SALES]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="##,###,###,###.00 ;##,###,###,###.00-" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="216" y="16" width="130" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{YTD_SALES}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="360" y="0" width="180" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="554" y="0" width="180" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESS_2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="749" y="0" width="180" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="792" height="16" uuid="0c8cb5ef-8a0f-49eb-8f4a-e4ef3d5b8101">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[   .                                                                                            ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="706" y="16" width="36" height="16" uuid="04ad0a74-a51c-4b93-967f-2c9e95d43db2">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATE}.equals("OH")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Lucida Console"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TOTAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="##,###,###,###.00 ;##,###,###,###.00-" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="749" y="16" width="123" height="16" uuid="c6c7ce27-82a1-467e-9894-eed6a42fe023">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{STATE}.equals("OH")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{OH_CITY_YTD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="1" uuid="c3bdd376-7d6f-4554-8e57-9f67873f4485">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{COLUMN_COUNT}>15)]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I need the variable OH_CITY_YTD to reset if there is change in the city for OH State but don't need the new page header and resetting the page number.
And how to print a blank line?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Please read the [ask] page and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You need to show how you try to display the page number, [edit] your question adding the jrxml

Comment: Your question is still some what unclear and your jrxml is not runnable for us. move group2 under group1.. and let me know... How to print a blank line?? add empty space...